# Can I configure FeignClient for work with different URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I write a payment system on Spring Boot. For integration with payment providers, I use FeignClient. I see that for different operations, deposit and withdraw, the different providers can use different URLs.  FeignClient allows for diferent reaquent use diferent URL?

What I mean:

```
@FeignClient(name = "ProviderName")
public interface ProviderClient {

     // Request to Provider deposit URL
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    DeposiResponse deposit(DeposiRequest request);

  // Request to Provider withdraw URL
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
    WithdrawResponse withdrawPrepare(@RequestBody WithdrawRequest withdrawRequest);
}
```

For example:

```
deposit: "https://pay.skrill.com/"
withdraw: "https://www.skrill.com/app/pay.pl"
```

Comment: How about [`url`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/FeignClient.html#url--) (+`path`) parameter(s)!?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare different paths in each of your Feign Client's methods:

```
// Request to Provider first URL
    @PostMapping(path="/url1", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    DeposiResponse deposit(DeposiRequest request);

  // Request to Provider second  URL
    @PostMapping(path="/url2", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
    WithdrawResponse withdrawPrepare(@RequestBody WithdrawRequest withdrawRequest);
```